# C - Sending data back and forth between processes

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc

I am working on the program below. What it is supposed to do is get the random int from the child process, and depending on the item_count variable, return the appropriate message to the child through the use of pipes. The problem is that I get a lot of unexpected behavior when executing, see below. myCatalog is a struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

struct catalog {
    char description[128];
    int price;
    int item_count;
};

int main() {
    int i, j, k, fd1[5][2], fd2[5][2];
    struct catalog myCatalog[3];
    pid_t pid;
    int itemNo;
    char message[24];
    char messageFailure[] = "Failure.", messageSuccess[] = "Success!";;        

 

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(pipe(fd1[i]) == -1) {
                printf("Error opening pipe 1!\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(pipe(fd2[i]) == -1) {
            printf("Error opening pipe 2!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0) { //Child
            time_t t;
            srand((int)time(&t) % getpid());
            
            close(fd1[i][0]);  //Close reading end of fd1
            close(fd2[i][1]);  //Close writing end of fd2
            
            for(k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                itemNo = rand() % 21;
                write(fd1[i][1], &itemNo, sizeof(int));
                sleep(1);
                read(fd2[i][0], message, sizeof(message));
                printf("%s\n", message);
            }
            printf("Hello from child process %d\n", getpid());
            close(fd1[i][1]);
            close(fd2[i][0]);
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(pid > 0) { //Parent
            int item;

            close(fd1[i][1]);  //Close writing end of fd1
            close(fd2[i][0]);  //Close reading end of fd2

            if(i == 0) {
                for(j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                    snprintf(myCatalog[j].description, sizeof(myCatalog[j].description), "Item #%d", j);
                    myCatalog[j].price = (rand() % 10) + 1;
                    myCatalog[j].item_count = 2;
                }
                for(j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                    printf("Description: %s\n", myCatalog[j].description);
                    printf("Price: %d\n", myCatalog[j].price);
                    printf("Count: %d\n", myCatalog[j].item_count);
                }   
            }
            for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                read(fd1[i][0], &item, sizeof(int));
                printf("%d\n", item);
                myCatalog[item].item_count = myCatalog[item].item_count - 1;
                if(myCatalog[item].item_count <= 0) {
                    write(fd2[i][1], messageFailure, sizeof(messageFailure));
                }
                else {
                    write(fd2[i][1], messageSuccess, sizeof(messageSuccess));                
                }
                sleep(1);
            }
            printf("Hello from parent process %d\n", getpid());
            close(fd1[i][0]);
            close(fd2[i][1]);
            wait(NULL);
        }
        else {
            printf("Error forking!");
            exit(1);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample output for one child process looks like this:

```
Hello from parent process 11868
Hello from child process 11890
6
Success!
4
Success!
3
Success!
4
3
16
Success!
14
3
6
3
18
3
20
3
18
3
```

What it should do is print the number, then either success or failure etc. Also, it shoots out 13 numbers sometimes instead of 10. The question is, where is the problem? Is it my piping? Is my loop usage completely wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `printf("error..."` is incorrect. Try `fprintf(stderr, "error....");`.  Errors belong on stderr.

Comment: I don't see "Success" anywhere in your code.  Show a complete example.  Include a `main` function and all #includes.  If I could cut-n-paste your code, I'd be willing to play with it.  I'm not willing to play with it in its current incomplete state.

Comment: @WilliamPursell that's not a requirement. It's not like the computer guesses whether the thing you're printing is an error message, and if so, doesn't print it unless you use stderr.

Comment: My apologies for getting to you so late, I have updated the snippet to include the complete program!

Comment: @user253751 It is certainly true that the computer can not guess that the message is an error message and refuse to print it to stdout.  That does not change the fact that it is incorrect to print error messages to stdout.  If anything, it makes it more important that the program do the right thing.  Error messages belong on stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly doesn't look right.   Accessing `myCatalog[n]` for n > 2 invokes undefined behavior.

```
  struct catalog myCatalog[3];
  ...
  for(j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
          printf("Description: %s\n", myCatalog[j].description);
```

Comment: Oh my, I was testing smaller sizes , I must have forgot to change it. Thank you very much for spotting it because I know I would have never looked there!

Comment: I do have a follow-up though. Everything prints fine now, except sometimes, it will print Failure for an item that has not been called 2 times. Is my approach to that part wrong? It seems that I am deducting item_count wrong. Again thank you very much and sorry if I'm being greedy with my second question!

Comment: @sntovas I would suggest checking the value returned by `read` to make sure you actually got a value.

Comment: It appears that the item_price field doesn't actually get decremented it actually assumes a random value, I wonder why?